# How can I add more god rays coming out of the holes?

Tags: light, volumetrics

I am trying to render my first volumetric lightning logo and there are two light planes inside the logo where the inscriptions "PC", "&i", processor are. So what I want is for these planes to create stronger god rays than they currently do. How can this be achieved?

[image]
[image]

**ADD:**

I tried the solution that @icYou sugested. So I imported my **.svg** file of my logo, converted it to mesh, opened edit, marked all vertices and removed doubles. I then deleted all vertices except the ones who form fonts "PC" and extruded the text. What I get are some weird black lines where only vloumetrics should be... These black lines were visible also in the Blender before rendering. It is kind of weird and I need an advice on this.

[image]

Comment: Could you provied blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ It could speed up an answer.

Comment: Doing this with volumetrics is slow and hard to control. This is generally done either with the sun rays compositing node or the BI spotlight composited into the cycles render (you can link two scenes' objects and have one render with BI and one with Cycles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding mist to the whole scene you can cheat and just put the rays over your text.

[image]

[image]

I just extruded the text in z space and gave it a volume scatter and absorbtion material. All you need to do is change the density to have it look stronger.

hope this could work for you.

EDIT :

The problem is with your SVG file. 
[image]
[image]

The "&" symbol and the other complicated part to the logo should only have the outline. You don't need all those lines inside the "&" symbol. So I would clean up the SVG file (edit>select all the vertices you dont need> delete). Make it as clean as possible. Also you need the inverse of SVG file. I would bring it back into Illustrator (or whatever you use) and Inverse the colors. You need the lettering to be extruding not the outline.

Here is a pic where you can tell the clean parts from the weird parts. 
[image]

If possible go back to illustrator clean up the logo so it is more basic (just for the god rays). When you import it into Blender make sure after you scale it up so you can see it, that you go to OBJECT>APPLY>SCALE. And only after that go to the curves tab and go to the extrusion setting and I put in .10, but adjust to your liking.

Comment: This is indeed a nice answer but how would I achieve the fading of the god rays with the distance?

Comment: Usually when you are dealing with .SVG files you need to scale them up after importing them. If you dont apply the scale you will get all sorts of weird things happening. If you are trying fade the rays you can always add a light falloff node into the density of your scatter and density nodes.  Also make sure your scatter and absorbtion nodes are pluged into the "volume" input and not the "surface" input on the material output shader.

Comment: I scaled up the file and it didn't help. What else can I do?

Comment: I would need to see your blend file to know exactly what going on.

Comment: Where can I upload and share my file? I prepared a 3D model with an imported SVG which I need to extrude... Can you try it?

Comment: You can always set up a free dropbox account and then send me the link .

Comment: This is it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpu9g3p0i98sup6/logotip.blend?dl=0

Comment: Ok I messed with it a little and updated my answer. I dont have time to do all the cleaning that the SVG file needs. But I hope this is enough info to get you pointed in the right direction. Here is the link to the blend file I was testing with. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr50tj9hx0891gi/logotip.blend?dl=0